# Does map reduce gives the same performance as spark if there is only one map reduce job?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata

Most of the bigdata jobs doesn't have a single mapreduce job, so the spark comes into play by storing the intermediate data in memory and avoiding the replication on the HDFS.

My question is what if there is only a single mapreduce job, say wordcount. Does the mapreduce job gives the same performance as spark? If not, why?

This might be a general question, but I am trying to understand the in depth architecture of spark.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p2110-shi.pdf) paper, Spark is 2.5x faster than mapreduce on wordcount. They attribute the difference to more efficient routing of the data from the map stage to the reduce stage

> For Word Count
>   and similar workloads, where the map output selectivity can be
>   significantly reduced using a map side combiner, hash-based aggregation
>   in Spark is more efficient than sort-based aggregation in
>   MapReduce. The execution time break-down result indicates that
>   the hash-based framework contributes to about 39% of the overall
>   improvement for Spark